# Who can add a new tag ticket-to-ride-nordic-countries?

Tags: support, tags

ticket-to-ride-nordic-countries

Is this the right place to ask to add a new tag?

Comment: We can't add a tag until there is a question to add it on. So if you have a question that has been asked that needs the tag provide a link and someone can add the tag to the question if appropriate.

Comment: Looks like there are [3 questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=ticket+to+ride+nordic+is%3Aq) that mention Ticket to Ride: Nordic Countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added it and applied it to two of the questions Andrew T. mentioned in comments:

- [Is there a list of routecards for Ticket to Ride: Nordic Countries?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42496/ticket-to-ride-nordic-counties-routecards)
- [Ferries and Tunnels in Ticket to Ride Expansions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1849/ferries-and-tunnels-in-ticket-to-ride-expansions)

I've left if off this one since although the expansion gets mentioned, it's just about the game in general:

- [How Unethical Is A Purely "Blocking" Move In Ticket To Ride?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/how-unethical-is-a-purely-blocking-move-in-ticket-to-ride)